# SQL SELECT query for LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-like

I have the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM student WHERE ssn LIKE '%321321%';
```

but it returns those records with 113213213215.  How can I change it so it only returns records that have 321321 subsequently ONLY.

Comment: Can you give example of wht result you expect and what you dont expect?

Comment: Okay. The results that the query should return are:

Comment: 113213215
13213216
321321
3213216

and not: 

3213213216
113213213217

Comment: what are so special abut these numbers: `113213215, 3213216, 1321321` than `113213213215`

Comment: I'm just looking for SSN that have 321321 pattern in it only.

Comment: are you aware that `113213213215` does contain the string `321321`?

Comment: yes but I only want it to return the string that contains 321321 and not 321321321...

Comment: So you mean only two consecutive occurrences of "321" and not any more? While ANSI SQL is the safest bet, it might still help to know what database you are using to perhaps leverage some specific functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the clarification in the comment you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM student
WHERE ssn LIKE '%321321%'
AND NOT ssn LIKE '%321321321%'; -- or: AND ssn NOT LIKE '%321321321%';
```

Keep in mind this will not work if you need to exclude arbitrarily long (>= 4) repetitions of `321`. You will need a more complex pattern matching solution if that is a requirement.

User `JW 웃` had posted a comment indicating a solution that would exclude all repetitions of `321` greater than 2 (I had initially thought it was wrong, and he deleted his comment, but he was correct):

```
SELECT ssn
FROM student
WHERE (LEN(ssn) - LEN(REPLACE(ssn, '321', ''))) / LEN('321') = 2;
```

If possible, I would extract that into a database function. In SQL Server this would look something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION SubStringCount
   (@SourceString varchar(max), @SubString varchar(max))
   RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
   DECLARE @fullLength int = LEN(@SourceString);
   DECLARE @subStringLength int = LEN(@subString);

   DECLARE @nonSubStringChars varchar(max) =
      REPLACE(@SourceString, @SubString, '');

   DECLARE @nonSubStringCharCount int = LEN(@nonSubStringChars);
   DECLARE @subStringCharCount int = @fullLength - @nonSubStringCharCount;
   DECLARE @subStringCount int = @subStringCharCount / @subStringLength;

   RETURN @subStringCount;
END
```

The query could then be written as:

```
SELECT ssn
FROM student
WHERE dbo.SubStringCount(ssn, '321') = 2;
```

Comment: Correct syntax: <something> **NOT LIKE** <somethingelse>

Comment: @PM77-1 `NOT X LIKE Y` seems to work. Is one preferable to the other in terms of performance or logic?

Comment: @SohelMansuri keep in mind this will not work if you need to exclude arbitrarily long repetitions of `321`.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT id from student WHERE locate('321321', ssn) > 0` should sort you, according to [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_locate). All the best...